# Horizontally centre a table

Tags: tabularx

any idea on how to horizontally center this Table within the page? Thank you very much. Regards.

[image]

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Fibre architecture of thermoplastic micro-fibre veils used for mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness testing (for the corresponding $G$\textsubscript{IC} results refer to Table \ref{table:veils2}). \textcolor{red}{centrar}}
    \label{table:veils1}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \makebox[\textwidth]{%
            \begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
                \toprule
                Reference         & Laminate      & Veil      & $\bar{\beta}$ (g/m\textsuperscript{2})     & $\omega$ ($\micro$m)      & $\rho$ (g/m\textsuperscript{3})\tnote{1} \\
                \midrule
                Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a} & \makecell{Carbon/epoxy (non-crimp \\ and plain-weave fabrics)} & \mr{CoPA} & \mr{21} & \mr{59} & 1.14 \\
                &   \makecell{Carbon/vynil ester (non- \\  crimp and plain-weave fabrics)}     &        &        &        &   \\
                Barjasteh \cite{Barjasteh2017} & Carbon/benzoxazine & PA12 & 12 & 17\tnote{2} & 1.25 \\
                Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} & Glass/vynil ester & PA66 & 17 & 25 & 1.14 \\
                O'Donovan \cite{ODonovan2014} & Glass/polyester & PA66 & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\
                Ramírez \cite{Ramirez2015} & Carbon/epoxy & PEEK & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\
                Ni \cite{Ni2015} & Carbon/epoxy & Aramid & 16 & 15 & 1.44 \\
                \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPE} & \mr{23} & \mr{12} & \mr{1.38} \\
                & Carbon/vynil ester & & & & \\
                Wong \cite{Wong2017} & Carbon/epoxy & Kevlar & 26 & 12 & 1.44 \\
                Fitzmaurize \cite{Fitzmaurice2016} & Glass/polyester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\
                Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} & Glass/vynil ester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\
                \mr{Beylergil \cite{Beylergil2018}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PA66} & 17 & \mr{19.90} & \mr{1.14} \\
                & & & 50 & & \\
                Ramírez \cite{Ramirez2015} & Carbon/epoxy & PPS & 7 to 35 & 10 & 1.30 \\
                & & & 8 to 22 & 14 & \\
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}
        \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
            \item[2] taken from \cite{matweb, polymer_handbook}
            \item[2] measured from a picture in \cite{Barjasteh2017}
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Vertically or horizontally centre?

Comment: Horizontally, sorry.

Comment: You already coded `\centering`, which centres the table between the margins. Beware that the default  left and right margins are no equal.

Comment: add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to your document to see that your table is already centered

Comment: How is the `\mr` macro defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the syntax of the `threeparttable` environment correctly: The `\caption` statement, when present, must be inside the `threeparttable` matter.

I would simplify the table layout by switching to a `tabularx` environment and letting the width of the second column adjust, as needed, so that the width of the full table is equal to `\textwidth`.

In addition, I would impose a bit more structure on the material in the table header, and I would use the `\si` macro (provided by the `siunitx` package) to typeset scientific units.

Finally, I had to make a guess as to how `\mr` is defined. I wouldn't be surprised at all if the guess isn't correct.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman font)
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mr[1]{#1} % ???
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Fibre architecture of thermoplastic micro-fibre veils used for \mbox{mode-I} interlaminar fracture toughness testing.
    (For the corresponding $G$\textsubscript{IC} results refer to Table~\ref{table:veils2}.)}
    \label{table:veils1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lLl *{3}{c} @{}}
          \toprule
          Reference & Laminate & Veil & $\bar{\beta}$ & $\omega$ & $\rho$\tnote{1}  \\
          & & & (\si{\gram\per\meter\squared}) & (\si{\micro\meter}) & (\si{\gram\per\meter\cubed}) \\
          \midrule
          Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a} 
            & Carbon/epoxy (non-crimp and plain-weave fabrics)
            & \mr{CoPA} & \mr{21} & \mr{59} & 1.14 \\
            &  Carbon/vynil ester (non-crimp and plain-weave fabrics)
            &        &        &        &   \\
          Barjasteh \cite{Barjasteh2017} & Carbon/benzoxazine & PA12 & 12 & 17\tnote{2} & 1.25 \\
          Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} & Glass/vynil ester & PA66 & 17 & 25 & 1.14 \\
          O'Donovan \cite{ODonovan2014} & Glass/polyester & PA66 & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\
          Ramírez \cite{Ramirez2015} & Carbon/epoxy & PEEK & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\
          Ni \cite{Ni2015} & Carbon/epoxy & Aramid & 16 & 15 & 1.44 \\
          \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPE} & \mr{23} & \mr{12} & \mr{1.38} \\
          & Carbon/vynil ester & & & & \\
          Wong \cite{Wong2017} & Carbon/epoxy & Kevlar & 26 & 12 & 1.44 \\
          Fitzmaurize \cite{Fitzmaurice2016} & Glass/polyester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\
          Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} & Glass/vynil ester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\
          \mr{Beylergil \cite{Beylergil2018}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PA66} & 17 & \mr{19.90} & \mr{1.14} \\
          & & & 50 & & \\
          Ramírez \cite{Ramirez2015} & Carbon/epoxy & PPS & 7 to 35 & 10 & 1.30 \\
          & & & 8 to 22 & 14 & \\
          \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

    \smallskip\footnotesize
    \begin{tablenotes}
       \item[1] taken from \cite{matweb, polymer_handbook}
       \item[2] measured from a picture in \cite{Barjasteh2017}
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```